# Proof of Authority or PBFT

Tags: consensus, poa, pbft

I want to choose a consensus algorithm for permissioned blockchain in healthcare. I know PoA and PBFT are good choices, but I want to know which one is better?
Thanks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to an abstract of [this](https://eprints.soton.ac.uk/415083/2/itasec18_main.pdf) paper:

> The analysis advocates that PoA for permissioned blockchains, deployed
>   over the Internet with Byzantine nodes, do not provide adequate
>   consistency guarantees for scenarios where data integrity is
>   essential. We claim that PBFT can fit better such scenarios, despite a
>   limited loss in terms of performance

Answer (score 0):

Proof of Authority (PoA) is a very well-tested consensus mechanism that has been used on [Kovan](https://wiki.parity.io/Proof-of-Authority-Chains) since it's inception. It has been used by a number of individuals as well as corporations in order to test their code in a controlled environment.

The initial [Plasma whitepaper](https://plasma.io/) suggested started with PoA (before switching to another mechanism), and the OMG team [is using PoA](https://blog.omisego.network/omisego-roadmap-update-94819e20ada2) on their Plasma implementation.